# Have to restart PC for second monitor to work

Tags: linux, windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card

If I restart the computer my monitors work as expected. From a cold boot one of the monitors does this:

The motherboard loading screen appears on the left screen (DVI to VGA) and then the right screen (HDMI) will display my boot options (Windows 10 or Linux) and keeps working as expected. Whatever I do the left screen (DVI to VGA) will keep on saying `Check Signal Cable`.

Thing is, I don’t have this behavior (error/issue) if I restart my computer.. it’s only on first start

I have two new Samsung s24d330 monitors. I didn't have this problem when using 2 HP monitors.

- Processor: Intel Core i5-3570K 3.4 GHz (from 2014)
- RAM: 16 GBs
- SSD: 512 GBs
- HDDs: 3 TOs
- Graphics: Nvidia GeForce GTX 760

Comment: My bad, question updated with suggested edit

Comment: First you say `DVI to VGA` then you say `DVI to HDMI`.

Comment: You are saying once your OS loads both screens work? Do both work in both OS?

Comment: Yes but only if I restart the computer , if I just start it, the left screen isn’t working no more passed the MotherBoard screen

Comment: Remove or improve this: `Thing is, I don’t have this behavior (error/issue) if I restart my computer.. it’s only on first start`